# Attach content of table 'row by row' to email message in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets, foreach, row

I'm struggling around to send email to myself with content of a table 'row by row'.
My needs are simple: I count a column and if the value is greater than 0, then my Google Trigger will check this (periodically) and send me an email. This works.

But I am not able to get the content of the lines (rows) into the 'message' to the Email, something like

Introtext:

- Row 1 | Info | Text
- Row 2 | Info | Text
- Row 3 | Info | Text
- ....

Screenshot of my table attached. The range I ask for in email message is 'A3:D' (if not blank).
So this is my simple code for now:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  // Fetch due Today
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DueToday").getRange("D1"); 
  var todaydue = myRange.getValue();

  // for now I check only one cell - but would like to get the set of rows (line by line)
  var myDetailsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DueToday").getRange("B3:B3");
  var myDetails = myDetailsRange.getValues();  
  var result = [].concat.apply([], myDetails).filter(String);

  // Check totals due today
    if (todaydue > 0) {
    // Send Alert Email
        var emailAddress = 'mymail@gmail.com'
        var subject = 'JRFgo² Reminder: ' + todaydue+ ' due today';
        var message = '‣ '+result+ ;
        GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and image and your expected result and "Introtext:". Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your expected result?

Comment: The 'introtext' is only for introduction message for the email, something like 'Below please find the items to review...' . Below of this 'introtext' should be the asking table. Sorry for making confusing (it's also about my poor english skills).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the relationship between your showing script and image and your expected result and "Introtext:". But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function sendEmail() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DueToday");//your Sheet name
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let message = "";
  const headersLength = 2;  
  
  //if lastRow is higher than 2, means there are rows with tasks
  if (lastRow > headersLength){

    //get all data range with tasks
    const data = sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow - headersLength,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    //Loop through each row to build the message
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      message+= `Row ${i+1} Data: ${data[i]}\n\n`

    }
    const subject = `JRFgo² Reminder: ${lastRow-headersLength} due today`;
    const emailAddres = "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddres, subject, message);
  }
}
```

This approach does not need the value from D1 to work since it checks the length of the sheet. Please note that if you remove or add more rows above the headers, you will need to update the headersLength value to match the number of rows to exclude from the data range with tasks

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm is exactly what I was looking for. I always try to understand the code. Would you be willing to explain the first part of the loop please? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. In that is a simple for loop, I declared var i as  0 so it will loop through each row from the bidimensional array (Data). On each iteration of the loop, I concatenate to the (message) the row position +1 plus the information on the specific row in the Data plus the "\n\n" whic is a double line break. If you want to better understand loops I suggest you visit this link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I am glad my answer helped you sort out the issue. When a post's answer solves the problem, it's a good idea for the person who asked the question to mark it as the correct answer. It helps others who might face the same problem later on.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I always had respect for these loops like 'foreach, for' etc but this helps a lot and I have to dare ;)